# How to specify sub project dependency between each other with cmake?

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have such project:

```
Root
  +-- SubA
  +-- SubB
  +-- SubC
  ...
```

All the sub folders have their own `CMakeLists.txt` And the one of Root looks like:

```
add_subdirectory(SubA)
add_subdirectory(SubB)
add_subdirectory(SubC)
```

If I start to build via `make` the 3 sub project will be built one after other and if I start via `make -j4` then the order might be random.

What I want to ask how to set the dependencies among these sub projects.  How to make the `SubB` and `SubC` depend on `SubA` so no matter waht `make -jX` is, the `SubB` and `SubC` won't be built until the `SubA` finishes.

Comment: Use the add_dependencies command: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html

Comment: @Vertexwahn I tried `add_dependencies(SubB SubA)` in the cmake file of Root folder but only get the error `Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target SubB`

Comment: You need set dependencies using `add_dependencies` for _targets_ instead of _subdirectories_.

Comment: @jayatubi Does `SubB/CMakeLists.txt` specify a target called `subB`?

Comment: @Biffen Yes. I used the folder's name as the target's name

Comment: @Gluttton So is there any way to set dependencies for *subdirectories*

Comment: @jayatubi `SubB` != `subB`

Comment: @jayatubi Can you show us the part of `SubB/CMakeLists.txt` that creates the target?

Comment: @jayatubi Oh, and you did put `add_dependencies()` *after* `add_subdirectory()`, right?

Comment: @Biffen I put `add_dependencies` before `add_subdirectory`. Should I change the order?

Comment: @jayatubi Yes. The target(s) won't exist before `add_subdirectory()`. Personally, I would put `add_dependencies(SubB SubA)` *inside* `SubB/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks. The order is the key.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR of the comments, thanks to Vertexwahn, Gluttton, and Biffen, the answer is to use [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html)

like so:

```
add_subdirectory(SubA) # creates target subA
add_subdirectory(SubB) # creates target subB
add_subdirectory(SubC) # creates target subC

# these must go after the targets are declared or else they will error about non-existent targets.
add_dependencies(subB subA) # subB waits for subA to build first
add_dependencies(subC subA) # subC waits for subA to build first
```